# C++11 Thread is joinable but join() raises an exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a strange issue with C++11 threads.
Unfortunately I cannot paste the full example (given the complexity) and I cannot replicate the issue on a simpler example.

So the problem is that I have a thread which is running (nor `join` nor `detach` has been called on it).
At some point another thread wants to stop this thread. The implementation simply set a boolean variable to false, and the call the `join` to wait for thread termination.

Well, the problem is the join.
I checked that the current thread (calling the join) is different from the joined thread and `joinable()` returns true.
Nevertheless this exception occurs:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: thread::join failed: No such process
```

This happens on macOS 10.11 but I had a colleague of mine test it on linux and it does not occur.

Any clue?

Comment: You say the code is complex, are you *sure* that `join` haven't been called somewhere else? Try to add more debug logging and tracing to see what's happening.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg wouldn't `joinable` return `false` if the thread was already joined?

Comment: True, so there's probably something other that is wrong. Since you can't replicate it in an MCVE, it's really impossible to say anything, but the problem is more probable to be your code and not the standard library. Try using memory debuggers such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar to see if you do something you should not do. And debug/trace logging is still a good idea if it's hard to step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: yeah.. I know it is difficult to say something without a simple example. I was hoping for some hints. I'll continue debugging

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with gcc 4.9. The thread is joinable but on join I got No such process (ESRCH, int=3 )

Comment: @norekhov on linux or macOS?

Comment: I think there lots in moving to a mcve, start stripping out code until it works, there is a chance the last bit of code removed before it starts to work will give you a good idea of what is wrong.

Comment: I already fixed. The problem was that a thread was created before fork() and after fork() there was no thread in app while C++ thought there's one. That's why join() on joinable thread threw an error ESRCH

Comment: @norekhov wow. But this is a great hint! The thread class works almost everywhere but in this hard-to-reproduce example. An in this example there is a call to `fork()`! I'll take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @norekhov if you put your comment in a "better form" and in an answer, I'll accept it. I had the same problem! the thread was created before the fork and joined in the child and not parent process!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might happen if you call fork() after creating additional threads in parent process. One important thing that differs the child process from the parent is that the child has only one thread.

So all C++ code which thinks there's a thread will be fooled and join() will throw 
"No such process". In this case because native call will return ESRCH.

You shouldn't create threads before calling fork().

Comment: or (I hope) in your newly created process think as all previous threads do not exists. BTW: fork and multithreading is discouraged everywhere :( (e.g. http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them)